# finding date before 30 days in hive-0.10.0

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I have 2 hadoop clusters, One has hive-0.10.0 installed and another has hive-1.1.0 version installed.

I am able to run below query in hive-1.1.0 which gives date before 30 days from present date

```
select date_sub(from_unixtime(floor(unix_timestamp()/(60*24*24))*60*24*24), 30)
```

But, the Same query is giving syntax error in hive-0.10.0

```
ok failed: parseexception line 1:79 mismatched input '' expecting from near ')' in from clause
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### 1.

Way too complected.
This will get you the same result:

```
select date_sub(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp()),30)
```

#### 2.

Queries without FROM clause are only supported from hive 0.13 
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-178

Create s table with a single row (similar to Oracle `dual`) and use it as source

Comment: This query giving same issues  in hive-0.10.0 version

Comment: OK FAILED: ParseException line 1:51 mismatched input '<EOF>' expecting FROM near ')' in from clause